# How to filter a list and convert into a 2d array while keeping the rich text values with formula in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of data where the cells are rich text values with a link.

**Data:**

| Fruits | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| [Apple](https://sample1.com) | 2 |
| [Orange](https://sample2.com) | 1 |
| [Pear](https://sample3.com) | 1 |
| [Cherry](https://sample4.com) | 2 |
| [Banana](https://sample5.com) | 2 |
| [Grape](https://sample6.com) | 1 |

---

**My criteria:**

1. extract `Fruits` with specified `Rank` (e.g. `1` or `2`)
2. transpose the output and split it into rows with a specified number of elements (max) in each row
3. keep the rich text value (link URL) in the output

---

**Example output:**

Rank: 1, max in each row: 2

| [Orange](https://sample2.com) | [Pear](https://sample3.com) |
| --- | --- |
| [Grape](https://sample6.com) |  |

---

**What I have tried:**

[A link to the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sAdfp1aX_3USC23Uzt-pEvVhxUydoNVah5pyx9CbhAI/edit#gid=0)

***1. `FILTER`***

The result keeps the link URL in the rich text value

`=FILTER(A:A,B:B=1)` in `D2`

| FILTER Output |
| --- |
| [Orange](https://sample2.com) |
| [Pear](https://sample3.com) |
| [Grape](https://sample6.com) |

But I do not know how to convert it into a 2d array nor `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` the result.

***2. `QUERY`***

I can create the desired 2d array with multiple `QUERY`

`=IFNA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A:B,CONCATENATE("SELECT A WHERE B=",1," LIMIT ",2," OFFSET ",(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*2),0)),)` in `F2` and applied to `F2:F3`

| Orange | Pear |
| --- | --- |
| Grape |  |

But the result does not keep the link URL in the rich text value

***3. With helper columns***

First, `FILTER`:

`=FILTER(A:A,B:B=1)` in `I2`

| FILTER Output |
| --- |
| [Orange](https://sample2.com) |
| [Pear](https://sample3.com) |
| [Grape](https://sample6.com) |

Second, convert into 2d array with `OFFSET`:

`=OFFSET($I$2,COLUMNS($I2:I2)-1+(ROWS($2:2)-1)*2,0)` in `K2` and applied to `K2:L3`

| [Orange](https://sample2.com) | [Pear](https://sample3.com) |
| --- | --- |
| [Grape](https://sample6.com) |  |

This outputs what I want but I do not want to use a helper column.

---

**My question:**

Is it able and how to achieve with formula and without helper columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(rank,max,IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(
COUNTIF(B2:B,rank)/max),max),{SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(B2:B,rank)),
FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=rank)},2,0)))(1,2))
```

But I suggest creating a Named Function `_WRAPROWS`  from **Data > Named functions > Create function** and using it like this:

```
=_WRAPROWS(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=1),2,)
```

Where `_WRAPROWS` is defined as:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(CEILING(
ROWS(FLATTEN(vector))/wrap_count),wrap_count),
{SEQUENCE(ROWS(FLATTEN(vector))),FLATTEN(vector)},2,0),pad_with))
```

#### Arguments:

- `vector` - The array to wrap.
- `wrap_count` - The maximum number of values for each row.
- `pad_with` - The value with which to pad.

See [WRAPROWS in Google Sheets](https://ztiaa.com/posts/wraprows-in-google-sheets) for more information.